# Apache/2.2.9, mod_perl/2.0.4: status_line doesn't seem to work

Tags: apache, mod-perl

Response is prepared this way:

```
my $r = Apache2::RequestUtil->request;
$r->status_line('500 Internal Server Error');
$r->send_cgi_header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n");
print 'Custom error message';
```

Request:

```
GET /test_page HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xxx.xxx
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: XXXXXXXXXX
Server: Apache/xxxxxxxx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

44
Custom error message
0
```

Why response status is 200 and not 500?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Registry script or a handler?

In a response handler, if you're setting a 4xx or 5xx status you need to return `Apache2::Status::DONE` rather than `Apache2::Status::OK`.

From http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/intro.html#Stacked_Handlers :

> HTTP handlers may also return
>   Apache2::Const::DONE which tells
>   Apache to stop the normal HTTP request
>   cycle and fast forward to the
>   PerlLogHandler, followed by
>   PerlCleanupHandler. HTTP handlers may
>   return any HTTP status, which
>   similarly to Apache2::Const::DONE will
>   cause an abort of the request cycle,
>   by also will be interpreted as an
>   error. Therefore you don't want to
>   return Apache2::Const::HTTP_OK from
>   your HTTP response handler, but
>   Apache2::Const::OK and Apache will
>   send the 200 OK status by itself.

Hope that helps - I remember having to spend quite some time looking for this in the docs, I don't think it's mentioned anywhere else!

Answer (score 1):

$r->custom_response(500, $custom_error_message) must be used for this purpose.